# Meta tag not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I try to add meta tag for facebook but it not working

I test on facebook debug it warning don't have fb meta tag but I add it already

this is my meta tag

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://app.soosky.co/">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Soosky - Interactive Game Ads for Marketing Campaigns">
<meta property="og:description" content="Soosky is a game based platform for advertising and branding. Create meaningful marketing campaigns, advertisements, and have fun spreading a game !">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://app.soosky.co/">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Interactive Game Ads for Marketing Campaigns">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://app.soosky.co/static/platform/images/frame3.png">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://app.soosky.co/static/platform/images/frame3.png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="640" /> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="442" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WPML ver:3.3.8 stt:1,2;" />
```

fb debug warning
[image]

Comment: This is what Facebook sees: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.soosky.co%2F . Why your server doesn't return anything I have no idea

Comment: I think it because I just change to https.

Comment: I try a web I make with http it run good

Comment: You’re missing a certificate in the chain, https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=app.soosky.co